# Make content span or grid collapse if the grid column is empty

Tags: javascript, css

I have a very simply 2 sidebar layout. I want to remove sidebar from the grid and let the rest of the content take over its space if it is empty.

HTML:

```
<div class="content container">
    <aside id="left-sidebar" class="secondary" itemtype="https://schema.org/WPSideBar" itemscope="itemscope">
        <div id="left-sidebar-container" class="sidebar-container"></div>
    </aside>
    <main class="primary"></main>
    <aside id="right-sidebar" class="secondary" itemtype="https://schema.org/WPSideBar" itemscope="itemscope">
        <div id="right-sidebar-container" class="sidebar-container"></div>
    </aside>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(0,.5fr) minmax(0,1fr) minmax(0,.5fr);
    grid-column-gap: 2.5%;
    grid-row-gap: var(--margin-bottom)
}
```

I have tried to use `grid-template-columns: minmax(0, auto) minmax(0,1fr) minmax(0,auto)`, but the `grid-column-gap` of that column would not go away.  Can I achieve what I want with pure css? Or I have to use some js instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript to achieve this by setting the display style of the left hand sidebar to `none` when there is no content. If I am correct in what you want, you are looking to remove the sidebar on the left if it is empty and have the primary andn right hand take over the grid, yes?

You could check to see if the `left-sidebar-content` text is empty using a conditional `=== ''`. If it is empty then set the display of your `left sidebar` class to `none`. When the `left-sidebar-container` has content then it will display the css originally defined as `display: grid`.

```js
let left = document.getElementById('left-sidebar-container'); //<-- get the left-sidebar-container with its id
let leftSB = document.getElementById('left-sidebar'); //<-- get the left-sidebar with its id
let content = document.querySelectorAll('.content'); //<-- get the .content element using it class
let check = left.textContent; //<-- save the textContent inside a variable
if(check === ''){ //<-- conditional if statement to see if the textContent is set to '' or empty
  leftSB.style.display = 'none'; //<-- set the display of the left-sidebar to none
}
```

```css
.content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(0,.5fr) minmax(0,1fr) minmax(0,.5fr);
    grid-column-gap: 2.5%;
    grid-row-gap: var(--margin-bottom)
}
```

```html
<h2>Nothing in left hand sidebar</h2>
<div class="content container">
    <aside id="left-sidebar" class="secondary" itemtype="https://schema.org/WPSideBar" itemscope="itemscope">
        <div id="left-sidebar-container" class="sidebar-container"></div>
    </aside>
    <main class="primary">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</main>
    <aside id="right-sidebar" class="secondary" itemtype="https://schema.org/WPSideBar" itemscope="itemscope">
        <div id="right-sidebar-container" class="sidebar-container">Right side bar</div>
    </aside>
</div>

<h2>Something in left hand sidebar</h2>
<div class="content container">
    <aside id="left-sidebar" class="secondary" itemtype="https://schema.org/WPSideBar" itemscope="itemscope">
        <div id="left-sidebar-container" class="sidebar-container">Left side bar</div>
    </aside>
    <main class="primary">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</main>
    <aside id="right-sidebar" class="secondary" itemtype="https://schema.org/WPSideBar" itemscope="itemscope">
        <div id="right-sidebar-container" class="sidebar-container">right side bar</div>
    </aside>
</div>
```